# Quicker Method to Group Numpy Array Elements Based on Second Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, structured-array

There are 2 NumPy arrays `groups` and `selectors`, where

1. `selectors` is an array containing integers that needs to be grouped

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

selectors = np.random.randint(0, 300, 5)
# [172  47 117 192 251]
```

2. `groups` is a structured array containing the first index (int) of a group (str)

```
# Generate groups `a` to `t` and their first index
start = ord('a')
groups = []
for i in range(20):
    e = (i*i, chr(start+i))
    groups.append(e)
groups = np.array(groups, dtype=[('index', np.uint32), ('selector', '|U1')])
groups = np.sort(groups, order='index')

# [(  0, 'a') (  1, 'b') (  4, 'c') (  9, 'd') ( 16, 'e') ( 25, 'f')
#  ( 36, 'g') ( 49, 'h') ( 64, 'i') ( 81, 'j') (100, 'k') (121, 'l')
#  (144, 'm') (169, 'n') (196, 'o') (225, 'p') (256, 'q') (289, 'r')
#  (324, 's') (361, 't')]
```

Given these example arrays, the desired result after grouping will be a dictionary of `np.ndarrays`/lists

```
{
    "g": [47] ,
    "k": [117],
    "n": [172, 192],
    "p": [251]
}
```

Is there a quicker way to perform this grouping in Numpy instead of nesting 2 loops, as shown below? This will be useful for large `selectors` arrays with 10-100 million rows using `groups` array with 100-1000 rows.

**Using Nested Loops**

```
results = {}
for s in selectors:
    for i in range(len(groups)-1):
        if s >= groups[i][0] and s < groups[i+1][0]:
            j = i
            break
    else:
        j = i + 1

    try:
        results[groups[j][1]].append(s)
    except KeyError:
        results[groups[j][1]] = [s]
print(results)
# {'n': [172, 192], 'g': [47], 'k': [117], 'p': [251]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use binary search on each selector, you are effectively changing the time of your routine from `O(len(groups) * len(selectors))` to `O(log2(len(groups)) * len(selectors))`

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) on the `bisect` module explains how to use it to find the right-most element less than or equal to a specified value.

Comment: Commenting on my on code.  This will be faster if groups is large enough.  I suspect that 100-1000, as you mention, is "large enough", but do some tests.